# PostgreSQL and can't run app

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I've been trying to locally run a web application via the Heroku toolbelt. But when I run

```
foreman start
```

I get the error

```
13:07:53 web.1  | started with pid 17115
13:07:54 web.1  | Listening on 5000
13:07:54 web.1  | Knex:Error Pool2 - error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "173.162.42.189", user "ktkfcfkvxupgsl", database "d7td7098ob0gcr", SSL off
13:07:54 web.1  | Knex:Error Pool2 - error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "173.162.42.189", user "ktkfcfkvxupgsl", database "d7td7098ob0gcr", SSL off
```

So I used the locate command to find this file in /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf and added

```
host   all    all    0.0.0.0/0   md5
```

and restarted/loaded the database server, but still got the same error back.
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 and am also new to pgsql. Can someone help me find out what's causing this issue? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What you did seems reasonable. If you run `SHOW hba_file` while connected as a superuser to the database, what path does it show?

Comment: @CraigRinger    
I used 'psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file;' and it gave me the same location '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf'